# Are decision trees related to maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart, artificial-intelligence

I am just curious if decision tree is conceptually related to maximum likelihood estimation. As far as I know, when a decision tree split, it uses entropy for its nodes. However, I don't know if using entropy to make modes in decision trees is related to maximum likelihood estimation or not. Hope to hear some explanation.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94886